# Comparar el dato de una matrices con un caracter

Tags: java, array, swift, poo, matrices

estoy empezando a programar en java, novata en este lenguaje,estoy haciendo un programa de asignación de asientos de cine, con lo cual lo estoy haciendo con una matriz de dimensión 6, pero a la hora de comparar la matrices con un caracter se ejecuenta bien pero le ingreso || (or) para compararlo con otro caracter y me sale error.

int f=5, c=5;
        String [][] asiento= new String [f][c];
        int opcion, compra, acomular;

```
    for (f=0;f<asiento.length;f++) 
    {
        for (c=0;c<asiento.length;c++) 
        {
            asiento[f][c]= ("L") ;
        }
    }

    for (f=0;f<asiento.length;f++)
    {

        for (c=0;c<asiento.length;c++)

                System.out.print("["+asiento[f][c]+"]");
                System.out.println(" ");
    }
     System.out.println();

    do{

        opcion=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Menùº:\n 1.Reservar\n 2.Comprar\n 3.Liberar\n 4.Salir\n Ingrese la opciòn deseada:\n"));

    switch(opcion){

    case 1: f=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la fila:"));
            c=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese la columna:"));

            if (asiento[f][c]=="L" || "R") (me sale error y ya probado con varios metodos y no da)
            {
                asiento[f][c]= ("V") ;  

                System.out.println("Asientos ");
                System.out.println();   

                for (f=0;f<asiento.length;f++)
                {
                    for (c=0;c<asiento.length;c++)

                            System.out.print("["+asiento[f][c]+"]");
                            System.out.println(" ");
                }           
             }
    break;
```

quisiera saber como se puede comparar una matriz con dos carácter.

Comment: Podrias editar la pregunta y agregar el error que te da

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sintaxis para el operador lógico `||` recibe booleans a ambos lados del operador.

En la expresión:

```
asiento[f][c]=="L" || "R"
```

Por el lado izquierdo tienes el booleano resultado de `asiento[f][c]=="L"` pero por el lado derecho hay un String.

La corrección para que compile sería:

```
asiento[f][c]=="L" || asiento[f][c]=="R"
```

Y la forma correcta de comparar sería:

```
"L".equals(asiento[f][c]) || "R".equals(asiento[f][c])
```

Los objetos en java deben ser comparados con el metodo `equals()`. Solo los primitivos se comparan con `==`

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio de mucho